# How to set <option> tag's width with <select> tag's using css?

Tags: html, css, html-select

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-6 valtype" id="pass_val">Type :
    <div class="">
      <select name="" aria-controls="" class="form-control select-focus">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="4"> Debtor out of area</option>
        <option value="5"> Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area</option>
        <option value="29">Consumer old</option>
        <option value="6">determine action</option>

      </select><span></span></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-6 valtype" id="pass_val">Type :
    <div class="">
      <select name="" aria-controls="" class="form-control select-focus">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="4"> Debtor out of area</option>
        <option value="5"> Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area</option>
        <option value="29">Consumer old</option>
        <option value="6">determine action</option>

      </select><span></span></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

I have drop down list but here is one problem that when content is increase then option's width also increase but select's width is remain same.

So i want that option's width remain equal to select's width if content will be increase.

Comment: Styling options and drop down lists is very limited - you may need to use a js plugin in order to do what you want - this is the one I usually use: https://select2.org/

Answer (score 1):

if I correctly understood your question is that you want  :
when you choose an option the select tag remains the same and does not change its size whatever the option is selected  so I propose my solution:

```css
#mySelect select
{ 
width:150px; 
}
```

```html
<div id='mySelect'>
      <select name="" aria-controls="" class="form-control select-focus">
        <option value="">Select</option>
        <option value="4"> Debtor out of area</option>
        <option value="5"> Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area Debtor out of area</option>
        <option value="29">Consumer old</option>
        <option value="6">determine action</option>

      </select><span></span></div>
  </div>
```

hope my answer can help you

Comment: I want both (select and option) tag width will be equal if option content is increasing. In my case Option width increasing when content is too large

Comment: try this solution which with jquery: https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Auto-resize-select-tag-element-width-according-to-option/        and don't  forget to import this jquery cdb in your project  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>